# I am getting error in spring batch with spring boot version 2.2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to read data from csv and insert into Database.

UserRepository file:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer > {
}
```

DBWriter file:

```
@Component
public class DBWriter implements ItemWriter<User> {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository ;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends User> users) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Data saved for users: "+ users);
        userRepository.save(users);
    }
}
```

**getting compile time error in userRepository.save method.**

***Inferred type 'S' for type parameter 'S' is not within its bound; should extend 'in.mmedia.spring_batch_example.model.User'***

Answer (score 1):

You should call `userRepository.saveAll(users);` and not `userRepository.save(users);`.

That said, Spring Batch provides the [RepositoryItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/data/RepositoryItemWriter.html) which can be used to write items based on a Spring Data repository.